# For reference and reference information, what are the basic Google technologies?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Edited question:

We all know that Google is one of the largest technology companies in the world and is a benchmark of innovation and cutting-edge technology for all of us and especially those who study technology.
I need to draw up a study plan, and since our time is scarce we need to come up with the best strategy, so I would like to be inspired by the ways and choices made by Google since it is a reference for all of us.
So I would like to know what technologies Google uses on its cloud platform in both infrastructure and OS as well as in the chosen development languages.

For example, it is known that Microsoft likes to use Hyper-v and C ++ and C # in its cloud, Amazon used Xen and now migrated to KVM ....

I do not want to "discover the secrets of Google", even because the secret lies in the great talented team that was company yes. I just want a reference of what they used, because there may be the best way forward.

Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a discussion site about external companies.

Comment: Okay, I apologize to you and the community.
But note that knowing what programming language was used in a successful project serves as a reference for our own projects.
I did not know this was restricted information, as for example I quote Docker, who opened his code and made it publicly available on Github.

Comment: @Vinícius For what it's worth, Google is known to have one of the most proprietary tech stacks of all the large tech companies. I would hesitate to use them as an example to generalize anywhere else.

Comment: Hello @MaximillianLaumeister, thank you very much for your advice. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some insight by looking into open source code written by Google Cloud folks:

- [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), [Istio](https://github.com/istio/istio), [gVisor](https://github.com/google/gvisor) and [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy) are written in Go.
- [GCE Guest Environment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages), [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install), [gsutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil) and [Spinnaker](http://www.spinnaker.io/) are written in Python.
- [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) is written for Java, Python and Go, with Java being the primary language.
- [Tensorflow](https://tensorflow.org) is written in Java and Python.

Answer (score 1):

First, it does not make sense to ask about programming languages in a scope as broad as the Google Cloud Platform. Many languages are used for many different parts of the platform.

Besides that, the software behind the platform is proprietary and not publicly available. For that reason, we can't tell you more than the obvious - Google Cloud Platform uses JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for contributing your answer and your opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is to be closed, how sad, but the answer is probably the same as ["What programming languages does Google use?"](https://www.quora.com/Which-programming-languages-does-Google-use-internally). This would make the answer a combination of mostly C++, Java, Python, and Go on the server, and others on clients, e.g. JavaScript and Swift.

Comment: Thanks for contributing your answer and your opinion :)
Its placement makes sense.
I ask because I found the platform somewhat slow as Microsoft's Azure.
That's why I was curious, just not to follow the same path ...